# Need to add Leading zeroes on kendo datepicker date selection

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to add leading zeroes to a kendo ui datepicker on date selection.

Like if I select **5 Jan 2013** in **kendo datepicker**
I need in the input text as **01/05/2013**. I see by default it returns as **1/5/2013**. Is there any workaround for this.

I have  mask on the input 
 **$dateControls.mask("99/99/9999");**

so every time it selects a single digit month or date , it does not select anything in the input at all, because it expects two digit month or day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$("").kendoDatePicker({
        format: "dd/MM/yyyy"
    });
```

Or, if you're using the .NET helpers:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Format("dd/MM/yyyy"))
```